# The ## operator in C

Tags: c

What does `##` do in C?

Example:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int bit0:1;
    unsigned int bit1:1;
    unsigned int bit2:1;
    unsigned int bit3:1;
    unsigned int bit4:1;
    unsigned int bit5:1;
    unsigned int bit6:1;
    unsigned int bit7:1;
} _io_reg;

#define REGISTER_BIT(rg,bt) ((volatile _io_reg*)&rg)->bit##bt
```

(I know what it all does besides the ## part.)

Comment: http://symbolhound.com/?q=C+%23%23

Answer (score 17):

It is [string concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html), as part of the preprocessor macro.

(In this context, "string" refers to a preprocessor token of course, or a "string of source code", and *not* a C-string.)

Answer (score 16):

It's called the pasting operator; it concatenates the text in `bt` with the text `bit`. So for example, if your macro invocation was

```
REGISTER_BIT(x, 4)
```

It would expand to

```
((volatile _io_reg*)&x)->bit4
```

Without it, you couldn't put a macro argument directly beside text in the macro body, because then the text would touch the argument name and become part of the same token, and it'd become a different name.

Comment: BEST CLARIFICATION THANKS :)

Answer (score 9):

The operator ## concatenates two arguments leaving no blank spaces between them:

```
#define glue(a,b) a ## b
glue(c,out) << "test";
```

Answer (score 3):

That's part of the macro definition.

It allows you to concatenate strings inside the macro.

In your case, you can use `bt` from 7 to 0 like this:

```
REGISTER_BIT(myreg, 0)
```

and it will be expanded as:

`((volatile _io_reg*)&myreg)->bit0`

Without this, you'd have to define the `bit` part of the macro as one of the macro's arguments:

```
#define REGISTER_BIT(rg,bt) ((volatile _io_reg*)&rg)->bt
```

where the usage would be:

```
REGISTER_BIT(myreg, bit0)
```

which is more cumbersome.

This also allows you to build new names.

Assume you have these macros:

```
#define AAA_POS 1
#define AAA_MASK (1 << AAA_POS)
#define BBB_POS 2
#define BBB_MASK (1 << BBB_POS)
```

and you want a macro that extracts AAA from a bit vector.  You can write it like this:

```
#define EXTRACT(bv, field) ((bv & field##_MASK) >> field##_POS)
```

and then you use it like this:

```
EXTRACT(my_bitvector, AAA)
```

Answer (score 3):

That is the [token pasting operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I know this is very old, but your old link is probably not pointing to where you originally intended.  Precisely why links used like this, i.e. without any other real information about what it contains, are not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a C construct, it's a [preprocessor feature](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation). In this case it's meant to evaluate the `bt` variable and concatenate it with the `bit` prefix. Without the hashes you would have `bitbt` there, which obviously would not work.

Comment: I don't think "evaluate the `bt` variable" is the right way of saying it... in the context of the preprocessor, "substituting the token" or something like that is the usual term. The preprocessor doesn't know anything about value; all it sees are string tokens (with a few exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from `ffmpeg`, a macro that registers both audio and video filters:

```
#define REGISTER_FILTER(X, x, y)                                        \
    {                                                                   \
        extern AVFilter ff_##y##_##x;                                   \
        if (CONFIG_##X##_FILTER)                                        \
            avfilter_register(&ff_##y##_##x);                           \
    }
```

and usage can be:

```
REGISTER_FILTER(AECHO,aecho,af);
REGISTER_FILTER(VFLIP,vflip,vf);
```